# Base class holding a reference to Derived

Tags: c++

I'd like to do this:

```
struct Derived;

struct Base{
    Derived const& m_ref;
    Base(Derived const& ref) : m_ref(ref){}
};

struct Derived: Base{
    Derived(): Base(*this){}
};
```

But I seem to get unreliable behaviour (when used later on, `m_ref` points to things that aren't valid Derived).

Is it permissible to construct a reference to Derived from `*this` before the class has been initialised?

I appreciate that it is not valid to *use* such a reference until it has been initialised, but I don't see how changes to the initialisation of a class can affect references to it (since initialising it doesn't move it around in memory...).

I'm not sure what to call what I'm trying to do, so my search for information on this has drawn a blank...

**Update:**
I can't reproduce my problems with a simple test case, so it looks like it is *probably* okay (though I can't prove it, and would still welcome a definitive answer).
Suspect my problems arose from a broken copy-assignment operator. That's another matter altogether though!

**Update 2**
My copy constructor and copy-assignment operators were indeed to blame, and now this seems to work reliably. Still interested in whether or not it is well-defined behaviour though.

Comment: `m_ref` doesn't point anywhere. It's not a pointer. It's a reference. </needless_pedanticism>

Comment: I'm pretty sure dereferencing `(Derived*)this` is invalid at this point (when the dynamic type of the object is still `Base`, and no such `Derived` exists yet). That's "using" it, no? That all said, I'd expect this to fail in _different_ ways than the ones you're experiencing, so perhaps there's something else going on too. Still, I have to ask: **why?!?!**

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? This smells of bad design.

Comment: I'm actually implementing a generic base class that takes a template parameter class and derives from it, and adds a "safe bool" conversion based on the result of a function call on the derived type. I'd like to avoid using virtual functions, if possible, because <s>I'm a serial premature optimiser</s> I really do care about performance in some of the places I'd like to use this.

Comment: This kind of solution is useful when dealing with templates and policies. In these cases it's perfectly legal. Just remember to document requirements for "Derived" class.

Comment: @Tomalak Well, I thought it was okay when the compiler (gcc 4.2) didn't warn me about it, but yes, I don't understand why it's breaking like it is.

Comment: I suppose an alternative design would be CRTP without the reference parameter, and a static Base->Derived cast instead.

Comment: I agree with  Tomalak and Johnsyweb. This smells of a bad design, and how could this work? When Base::Base is called Base hasn't been fully constructed yet. So how could Derived::Derived possibly work here? You have a circular problem here. Base::Base depends on Derived::Derived to construct that reference, but Derived::Derived depends on Base::Base because Derived inherits from Base.

Comment: @gwiazdorrr: Please prove that it's legal.

Comment: @Tomalak: 3.8/5: "such a pointer may be dereferenced, but the resulting lvalue may be used only in limited ways". Please prove that it's illegal.

Comment: @Tomalak: note also 12.6.2/7: "[Note: because the mem-initializer are evaluated in the scope of the constructor, the this pointer can be used in the expression-list of a mem-initializer to refer to the object being initialized.". I don't know what that means, if it doesn't mean that the `this` used in `Base(*this)` is already a pointer to `Derived`, just like it would be in the body of `Derived()`.

Comment: @Steve: Thankyou. The full `Derived` object is not yet constructed in the ctor-initialiser (in fact, not until the body runs). That's why the quoted clauses surprise me, but there we go.

Comment: @Tomalak: I'm still stuck myself, mind you, I just don't think there's a problem with the expression `*this`. See my answer for how far I've got...

Comment: @Steve: re recent additions to your answer, glad you had the time to prove it illegal (whereas I did not) :)

Comment: @Tomalak: I don't think I've really proved it, there's still language I don't understand. I don't know when the object becomes "valid" (start of constructor / end of constructor). Is my example with `self` UB, is it also UB to use `*this` in a constructor as an argument to a function that takes a reference parameter? Or maybe all this is fine, and is covered by "the lvalue can be used in any way that doesn't depend on the value" in 12.6.2/7?

Comment: @Steve: Having pored through the standard a bit, I'm not entirely convinced now either. Meh. (Though, w.r.t. your `self` example, the object's members (and its base) _are_ constructed before the ctor body is invoked, so that's not the same at all.)

Comment: @Steve: I've posted what I think is a semi-convincing answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3.8/1 says:

> **The lifetime of an object of type T
>   begins when**: — storage with the proper
>   alignment and size for type T is
>   obtained, and — if T is a class type
>   with a non-trivial constructor (12.1),
>   **the constructor call has completed**.

3.8/5 says:

> **Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated**
>   or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is
>   reused or released, **any pointer that refers to the storage location where the object will be or was located
>   may be used but only in limited ways**. Such a pointer refers to allocated storage (3.7.3.2), and using the
>   pointer as if the pointer were of type void*, is well-defined. **Such a pointer may be dereferenced but the
>   resulting lvalue may only be used in limited ways, as described below.**

"Below" is 3.8/6:

> Such an lvalue refers to allocated storage (3.7.3.2), and using the properties of the lvalue which do not
>   depend on its value is well-defined.

...and then a list of things you can't do. Binding to a reference to the same, derived type is not among them.

I can't find anything elsewhere that might make your code invalid. Notably, despite the following phrase in 8.3.2/4:

> A reference shall be initialized to
>   refer to a valid object or function.

there doesn't seem to be any definition of "valid object" to speak of.

So, after much to-ing and fro-ing, **I must conclude that it is legal**.

---

*Of course, that's not to say that it's in any way a good idea!* **It still looks like a bad design.**

For example, if you later change your base constructor and any of the following become relevant (again from 3.8/6):

- the lvalue is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object
- the lvalue is implicitly converted (4.10) to a reference to a base class type
- the lvalue is used as the operand of a `static_cast` (5.2.9) (except when the conversion is ultimately to `char&` or `unsigned char&`
- the lvalue is used as the operand of a `dynamic_cast` (5.2.7) or as the operand of `typeid`.

...then your program will be undefined, and the compiler may emit no diagnostic for this!

---

**Random other observations**

I notice a couple of other *interesting* things whilst compiling this answer, and this is as good a place as any to share them.

First, 9.3.2 appears to leave the type of `this` in a *ctor-initializer* accidentally unspecified. Bizarre!

Second, the criteria set on a pointer by 3.8/5 (not the same list that I quoted from 3.8/6) include:

> If the object will be or was of a
>   non-POD class type, the program has
>   undefined behavior if [..] the
>   pointer is implicitly converted (4.10)
>   to a pointer to a base class type.

I believe that this renders the following innocuous-looking code undefined:

```
struct A {
   A(A* ptr) {}
};

struct B : A {
   B() : A(this) {}
};

int main() {
   B b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in general you're OK doing this, but be very careful in constructors and destructors. In particular, in `Base::~Base`, the `Derived` part of the object has already been destroyed so don't use `m_ref` there.

Comment: there are many such **coward** down voters in SO, who doesn't care to comment after casting their votes.

Comment: @iammilind: Agreed, but it couldn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 2):

3.8/6 says what you can do with a pointer/reference to memory for an object that has been allocated but not yet constructed. Your code doesn't provoke an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, or otherwise break the rules, so I'd think that you're fine. Since you're observing bad values, though, I may well have missed something. Or your code might be otherwise bad.

Even if you did break those rules, 12.6.2 and 12.7 list additional things that you can do *during* construction and destruction.

Edit: ah, 8.3.2/4: "A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object
or function." You initialize `m_ref` to refer to an object whose constructor hasn't even been entered yet. I don't know without further research whether an object under construction is "valid" or not, and in particular whether the object of most-derived type is "valid" at the time of construction of the base class. This could perhaps be the problem, though.

You might think that no unconstructed object is "valid", but then this would be invalid:

```
class Foo {
    Foo() {
        Foo &self = *this; // reference initialized to refer to unconstructed object!
    }
};
```

So, is that invalid? If not, does the most-derived object become valid somewhere between the start of the base class constructor call and the start of the derived class constructor call? I dunno, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think the big problem in this is that you think you want to do one thing, when in reality you actually want to do something else. Strange, huh?

> Is it permissible to construct a reference to Derived from *this before the class has been initialised?

Yes, as long as you don't **use** it (for anything but storing a reference to it) in the scope of the Base constructor and remember in ~Base that Derived is destroyed before Base.

But why on earth do you think that Base wants to know of Derived? If it's static polymorphism you are after, then the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) is what you want:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {};
```

But I don't really think that's what you're aiming at.

Maybe you want a way for Base to communicate with a client and think that should be done with inheritance? If so, then this observer-ish idiom is what you need:

```
class Client
{
public: 
    virtual void Behavior() = 0;

protected:
    ~Client() {}
};

class Base
{
    Client& client_;

public:
    Base(Client& client) : client_(client) {}
};

class Implementor : public Client
{
public:
    Implementor() : Base(*this) {}

    virtual void Behavior() { ... }
};
```

If not even that is what you want, then you need to rethink your design.

Comment: "Yes, as long as you don't dereference it in the scope of the Base constructor" that's exactly what he's doing. Pretty much.

Comment: @Tomalak: No, that's pretty much not at all what he's doing. All he does in his example is **assign** the reference and that's completely defined, allowed and safe. The compiler warning is there for those that have no clue of the issues that might arise from passing `this` to a base class. Those issues are described by me and others.

Comment: There is no such thing as assigning a reference, and `*this` involves a dereference operation to produce the reference in the first place.

Comment: @Tomalak: Sorry, I see what you mean now with **dereference**. I simply meant **use** as in call functions on it. Word-mixup; I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm actually implementing a generic base class that takes a template parameter class and derives from it, and adds a "safe bool" conversion based on the result of a function call on the derived type. I'd like to avoid using virtual functions, if possible, because <s>I'm a serial premature optimiser</s> I really do care about performance in some of the places I'd like to use this. – Autopulated 37 mins ago

You don't need a reference to the Derived class. Your class is deriving from a template parameter. Just use the common method.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Base : public T
{
public:
    bool operator!() const 
    {
        return !this->isOk();
    }
};

class TemplateClass
{

public:
    bool isOk() const
    {
        return true;
    }
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Base<TemplateClass> myClass;

    if (!!myClass)
    {
        std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "not ok" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can even use template specialization if you know ahead of time of derived classes that don't implement a common bool check.