# Passing class member to base class constructor (by reference)

Tags: c++

Given the following classes where `ConcreteBar` implements `BarIfc`:

```
class Base {

public:

    Base(BarIfc& bar) : _bar(bar) { }

    void foo() {
        _bar.bar();
    }

private:

    Base(const Base& other);
    Base& operator=(const Base& other);

    BarIfc& _bar; // Pure virtual interface
};

class Child : public Base {

public:
    // bar is passed to base class before initialization
    Child(int i) : Base(_bar), _bar(i) { 
    }

private:

    Child(const Child& other);
    Child& operator=(const Child& other);

    ConcreteBar _bar;
};
```

Am I right in assuming that this

```
Child(int i) : Base(_bar), _bar(i) {}
```

is "valid" C++ as long as I'm not using (e.g. calling a method) `_bar` reference within the initializer list of the base class?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<sub>*Under the assumption that ConcreteBar is a subobject*</sub>

It is valid since the storage has been allocated for §3.7.5/1

> The storage duration of member subobjects, base class subobjects and
>   array elements is that of their complete object (1.8).

and §3.8/5 says:

> Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage
>   which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the lifetime
>   of an object has ended and before the storage which the object
>   occupied is reused or released, any pointer that refers to the storage
>   location where the object will be or was located may be used but only
>   in limited ways. For an object under construction or destruction, see
>   12.7 [referring to non-static member usage]

so that is valid as long as you don't use the reference.

Comment: It it valid to use the reference after the lifetime started?

Comment: Lifetime of the reference is exactly its storage duration. For the object it points to it is safe since lifetime is a concept that consumers should pay attention to.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it's valid, because while `_bar` hasn't been constructed yet, the storage for it does exist, and taking a reference to it is OK so long as you don't actually use that reference until you're in the derived class constructor body.

Here's another post on a similar topic that you may find illuminating: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905746/4323

And finally, an answer which quotes the standard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6258431/4323 saying:

> Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage
>   which the object will occupy has been allocated [...],
>   any pointer that refers to the storage
>   location where the object will be or was located may be used but only
>   in limited ways.